# Script tag in PHP function - expecting statement

Tags: javascript, php, function

I'm trying to use JavaScript code in a PHP function, but I get the error - `expecting statement`

Code:

```
<?php
    function subscribe_request($phone) {
    <script src="js/subscrie.js" type="text/javascript">
        //something
    </script>
}
?>
```

Comment: Is this actually how your code is written?

Comment: You need to escape out of PHP to express non-PHP functionality, or echo/print it out.

Comment: That JavaScript won't run until it's in the browser, and it's never sent to the browser because it's inside a PHP function. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm assuming this is how the PHP was written. I added in the `<?php` tags as they were completely omitted. You can add `<script>` tags inside of PHP, but you'll need to close the PHP tags, then write the JavaScript, then open the PHP tags, then close the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the script in echo or store it in variable.

**Change From this:**

```
<?php
    function subscribe_request($phone) {
    <script src="js/subscrie.js" type="text/javascript">
        //something
    </script>
}
?>
```

**With this:**

```
<?php
    function subscribe_request($phone) {
    $script = '<script src="js/subscrie.js" type="text/javascript">';
    $script .= 'alert("' . $phone .'")';
    $script .= '</script>';
    echo $script;
}
?>
```

Comment: and how I use the $phone variable in the JS?

Comment: Thnk you very much, helps me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

HTML Code **cannot be** wrapped by `<?php>` tags.

Here's a another way to do it.

```
<?php
    function subscribe_request($phone) {
?>
        <script src="js/subscrie.js" type="text/javascript">
            // something
        </script>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Change your code and it should work fine